# Rails custom class static init

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, initialization

Given a class

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
  Rails.logger.info "Foo loaded"
end
```

located in `#{Rails.root}/app/lib`. I added to `config/application.rb` the following:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/lib)
```

When I startup rails either via `rails s` or `rails console`, I would like to see `Foo loaded` being logged. This is a simplified version of what I am intending to do, but it adequately demonstrates what I am trying to achieve. Currently, what happens is that nothing is logged at startup. Then, when I explicity use Foo, for example with `Foo.new`, I see the message logged.

What is the most appropriate method in Rails 3 to accomplish this so I see the logged message at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

(1) In the class `app/lib/foo.rb`, i added a static method to require the appropriate files

```
def self.load_foos
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/lib/foos/*_foo.rb"].each do |file|
    require file
  end
end
```

(2) in `foo.rb`, I added a static method so that subclasses could register themselves

```
def self.register 
  if @@subclasses.include?( self.registration_symbol )
    raise FooExceptionSymbolAlreadyUsed, "symbol [#{self.registration_symbol}] is already in use."
  end
  @@subclasses[self.registration_symbol] = [self.registration_priority,self]
end
```

(3) I created a directory at `app/lib/foos` where in I put the various subclasses of foo and named them `this_foo.rb` and `that_foo.rb`.

(4) In the subclass `app/lib/foos/this_foo.rb`, I added the following

```
class Foos::ThisFoo < Foo

  def self.registration_symbol
    :this
  end

  def self.registration_priority
    100
  end

  # other methods removed to make example easier to read

  register
end
```

(5) I added a `config/initializers/load_foos.rb` which simply had

```
Foo::load_foos
```

Any subclass of Foo that I put in `app/lib/foos/` and name correctly, will automatically be loaded at startup. Each subclass overrides and implements the methods for `registration_symbol` and `registration_priority` (the priority is used later to sort an enumeration) and the symbol is used in a create method.

Thus, I can publish a spec to my developers that shows them which methods of Foo to implement in their subclasses and how to register it and where to save it and then the Rails application will automatically load those files on the next startup.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation - I had a whole bunch of constants in my models that really only needed to be loaded once, when Rails started, but seemed to be getting reloaded every time I accessed that model.  I solved it as follows:

1. I defined the constants in a file in config/initiaizers (files there are loaded automatically at startup)
2. I added methods to my models that accessed those constants

If you're dealing with constants (e.g. `Foo::PI = 42`), this should work for you.  If you're defining methods...  maybe?  You might run into some problems in development mode, when Rails reloads classes that have changed - I'm not sure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am looking to use methods. `config/initializers` was one of the methods I had been considering. Just looking to see if that is the appropriate manner to solve this or if there was something different/better. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails development environment, while wonderful for developing, is a bit odd about loading and requiring.

However, if you use a standard Ruby require you will find things more predictable. I would suggest you leave as much as possible using the rails `config.autoload_paths`

For the code you want to always require, just add a `require 'app/lib/foo'` at the very end of your config/application.rb, outside the module definition.

Also, typically lib is at the root of the rails directory, not in the app folder. Was that a type or a conscious choice?

Comment: Yes, there is a lib directory in the `Rails.root`. The `'lib/` in my example could have easily been `squishy_banana_gold/` except `lib/` was quicker to type. thanks for the answer.